# Zip multiple files and download using php codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter, download, zip

I am trying to create a zip file including 2 text files and download it. Here is my code. $fda and $fwl are 2 array datas.

```
        $dataZip = array(
            './downloads/fda.in' => $data1,
            './downloads/fwl.in' => $data2
        );
        $this->zip->add_data($dataZip);
        $this->zip->archive('./downloads/files_backup.zip');
        $this->zip->download('files_backup.zip');
```

But it always returns error as a wrongly formatted string and nothing is downloaded.

```
fda.in�X�n�0}�+�
```

Could anybody tell me where I was wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out the solution. All I have to do is add ob_start(); in the open of the controller file.

```
        ob_start();
        $dataZip = array(
            './downloads/fda.in' => $fda,
            './downloads/fwl.in' => $fwl
        );
        $this->zip->add_data($dataZip);
        $this->zip->archive('./downloads/files_backup.zip');
        $this->zip->download('files_backup.zip');
```